# Sequences and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics

If $p, q, r$ are in G.P. and the equations:
$$px^2 + 2qx + r = 0$$ $$dx^2 + 2ex + f = 0$$
Have a common root, then show that 
$$\frac{d}{p}, \frac{e}{q}, \frac{f}r$$
are in A.P.

Well I tried taking the sum and products of the root, but that didn't get me anywhere. I was told that there is an extremely short way of doing this problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $p, q, r$ are in G.P., let $q=pR, r=pR^2$. 
$$\begin{align}
px^2+2qx+r&=0\\
px^2+2pRx+rR^2&=0\\
x^2+2Rx+R^2&=0\\
(x-R)^2&=0\\
x&=-R
\end{align}$$

Let $\dfrac dp=\lambda, \dfrac eq=\mu, \dfrac fr=\gamma$.

$$\begin{align}
dx^2+2ex+f&=0\\
\lambda px^2+2\mu qx+\gamma r &=0\\
\lambda px^2+2\mu pRx+\gamma pR^2&=0\\
\lambda x^2+2\mu Rx+\gamma R^2&=0\\
\end{align}$$

We are told that both equations have the same root, hence $x=-R$ is a root.

$$\begin{align}
\lambda R^2-2\mu R^2+\gamma R^2&=0\\
\lambda -2\mu +\gamma &=0\\
\gamma -\mu&=\mu-\lambda\\
\end{align}$$

i.e. $\lambda, \mu, \gamma$ are in A.P.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As  $\displaystyle\frac qp=\frac rq, pr=q^2$

The roots of the first equations are $$x=\frac{-2q\pm\sqrt{4q^2-4pr}}{2p}=-\frac qp$$

Set this value in the second and replace $q^2$ with $pr$